# Using a python script to run a shell script (containing a make file and an executable for fortran)

Tags: python, shell, fortran90

I am trying to execute a shell script using python. The shell script contains variables (which I want to set in the python script itself), a make file and an executable file for fortran. Is it possible to be done using python?
I tried with the following python code but unfortunately it does not work:

```
import subprocess import os import shutil

os.environ['FLUID'] ="MDM" 
os.environ['TTYPE'] = str(0) 
os.environ['FLIBRARY'] = "RefProp" 
HSPACE=[0.01, 0.009, 0.008, 0.007]

os.chdir(tmesh_dir)

subprocess.call(['./testfile3', str(FLUID), str(TTYPE), str(FLIBRARY)]
+ [str(n) for n in HSPACE])
```

testfile3 is a shell script which has the following contents:

```
fluid=$1; shift
ttype=$2; shift
flibrary=$3; shift
hspace=( "$@" )

make clean
make -j2

./vls.exe <<<"$fluid, $flibrary"

for i; do

cd Db

awk -v a="$i" 'NR==8 {$1="     " a }1' spacingcontrol.vls > tmp.vls && mv tmp.vls spacingcontrol.vls 
awk -v b="$i" 'NR==8 {$2="  " b "      "}1'  spacingcontrol.vls > tmp.vls && mv tmp.vls spacingcontrol.vls

done 

cd ..
umg/mcrv.exe
umg/bgrid.exe
umg/umg2d.exe

#make clean
```

Comment: Where are `FLUID`, `TTYPE`, etc defined?  Why are you trying to set the environment variables if your passing them into the shell script?

Comment: @BrendanAbel I am trying to define them in the python and then pass them to shell script.

Comment: I don't think the usage of the shift command in the script is correct, either use shift and 3 times $1 or just use $1, $2 and $3

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), which allows you to pass in a set of environment variables to the process.  You can also specify the working directory for the subprocess instead of changing the current one.

```
env = dict(os.environ)
env['FLUID'] ="MDM" 
env['TTYPE'] = str(0) 
env['FLIBRARY'] = "RefProp" 
HSPACE=[0.01, 0.009, 0.008, 0.007]

cmd = ['./testfile3', env['FLUID'], env['TTYPE'], env[FLIBRARY]]
cmd.extend([str(n) for n in HSPACE])

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=env, cwd=tmesh_dir)
```

Comment: As far as the reading of variables is concerned this works, however the make file of the fortran is not compiled, I get this error: 'ifort -c  -O0 -C -traceback -I /api/f90  kinds.f90'
'make: ifort: Command not found'
'make: *** [kinds.o] Error 127'
'testfile3: line 14: ./vls.exe: No such file or directory'

Comment: The compiler is properly installed because when I run the testfile3 as standalone through the terminal it works perfectly.